How to find the entries in the child with the specified value?

Under "support_calender", there are multiple "date" children eg 2024-04-11. In the "date", there are multiple entries. Based on my given location such as HC21, how can I find ALL the correct entries with "remark", "supportType" IF the "location" is same as my given value?

Do you need to get all nodes of a specific date or all nodes of all dates?

You can find the relevant child nodes for a given day with ref.child("2024-04-15").orderByChild("location").equalTo("HC21"). There's no way to search across all dates though. See the question I linked for more on that.

what if the date is not defined?
